# Let G be a graph with 2n vertices where every

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

Let G be a graph with vertices where every vertex has degree at least 2n. Prove that G is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, on the contrary, that there is a vertex $v$ of degree $2k$ but graph $G-v$ has more than $k$ components. Then there exists at least one  component $G_0$ which is connected to $v$ by exactly one edge $uv$, where $u\in G_0$. Then the vertex $u$ is odd degree.  The other vertices of $G_0$ have even degree by hypothesis. This contradicts the handshaking lemma for the graph $G_0$.